# Screen responds when button is clicked

Tags: java, libgdx

Basically, I have a screen where I have a character and a button. Character jumps when I touch the screen (implemented using Gdx.input.justTouched). The button opens PauseMenu when clicked (button is an actor of a stage and click is implemented using button.addListener(new ChangeListener() {.... }). My InputProcessor is set on stage

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

The problem is when the button is clicked my character jumps (but he shouldn't) and the pause menu opens. I was searching through InputMultiplexer but that didn't work (or maybe I used it in a wrong way).

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: i think you need to use an event with more information than `justTouched` and when you handle that event you can check if it is in the area of the button and ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `InputMultiplexer`.

First how the `InputMultiplexer` works.
In the `InputMultiplexer` you can do many `InputProcessor`s and an `InputProcessor` has methods which return boolean.
This boolean value says whether the event was handled or not.
So if the method returns false, the `InputMultiplexer` give the event to the next `InputProcessor`.
If the method returns true the event was handled and the event won't go to the next `InputProcessor`.

Now we make an `InputProcessor` for our screen in this case `TestScreenInput`:

```
public class TestScreenInput implements InputProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println("Touch down");
        character.jump();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    ... //all other methods from InputProcessor
}
```

The `touchDown` method returns true, so the next InputProcessor won't receive the `touchDown` event

In our screen class (TestScreen) we create our `Stage`:

```
public class TestScreen implements Screen {
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        stage = new Stage();
    }
}
```

Now we will create our `TextButton` with a `ChangeListener`.
The problem is, how we can say that the event is handled?
The `ChangeListener::changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor)` doesn't return a boolean.

When we look into the `Stage` class we can find the `touchDown` method and the method returns:

```
boolean handled = event.isHandled();
return handled;
```

`event` is a Type of `Event` and `ChangeEvent` extends `Event`
In our `changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor)` method we have a `ChangeEvent`. So all we have to do is to set this event handled.
In `Event` there is a method:

`public void handle () { handled = true;}`

Now we know all to create our Button:

```
TextButton button = new TextButton("Click", skin);
button.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        System.out.println("Click Button");
        event.handle(); //set the event handled = true
    }
});

stage.addActor(button);
```

Finally, we create our `InputMultiplexer`. Important is that the stage come before our `TestScreenInput` because the `TestScreenInput` will mark the `touchDown` as handled and the `stage` never will receive them.

```
InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
multiplexer.addProcessor(new TestScreenInput());
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

Comment: Yes, that worked and your explanation is very clear, thank you!

Comment: @Morchul "become" sounds like a German false friend in given context. Probably you meant "receive" ; ]