# How to prevent clickevent on Screen when actor is touched ? (LIBGDX)

Tags: libgdx

I have a :

- Screen implementing InputProcessor
- A stage created in the screen.
- an Actor added to the stage
- the Actor has a InputListener with a touchUp method, which is called when the actor is touched.
- When clicking on the actor the method touchUp of the actors inputlistener is called and the touchUp from the InputProcessor is also called.

Question:
How can I prevent calling the touchup method from the screen ? My goal is only to handle the event from actor. I would like to only react on the touch from the actor and not also from the screen.

Comment: The way you described it the actor will never get an input event. For that, it is needed that your State is the InputProcessor. So how did you set up the Multiplexer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a references to help you better understand my answer:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputListener.html#touchDown-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent-float-float-int-int-

That link shows one of the methods in the `InputListener` class. In your question, you asked about the `touchUp` method which is also related to the `touchDown` method.

The `touchDown` method returns a boolean while `touchUp` is void. Because of this, you can't cancel a "touch up" event. However, you can "cancel" a "touch down" event by returning true. I say "cancel" because it's not really cancelling it, it's just letting the implementation know that you are handling the "touch down" and "touch up" events now.

Using the `touchDown` method is probably your best option. I believe you will still be able to use `touchUp` but I am unaware if other listeners receive the `touchUp` call if `touchDown` returned true (Given the documentation, I don't think they will). That's something you'll have to test for yourself.

---

Now if you really need cancel a "touch up" event, do this:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Event.html#cancel--

You can try to cancel the event. Because the `touchUp` method in `InputListener` passes an `InputEvent` object, you can try to cancel it using `inputEvent.cancel()`

Answer (score 0):

If you will catch Events like touchUp, touchDown etc. you must say that the event is handled otherwise the event will run to the next InputListener until one Listener says that the event is handled.

To set the Event to handled you must call the `handle()` method on the event object:

```
actor.addListener(new InputListener(){
    @Override
    public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        event.handle();
    }
});
```

Here it is described a little bit more with InputMultiplexer: [Screen responds when button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412742/screen-responds-when-button-is-clicked/52421291#52421291)